# Plot two columns against eachother

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I don't think this should be difficult, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to do it.

I am trying to make a chart of age vs BMI. I have a column with age and a column with BMI. The table looks something like this:

```
-------------
| Age | BMI |
-------------
|  5  |  13 |
|  6  |  22 |
|  5  |  21 |
|  7  |  15 |
```

There are more columns, but that isn't important right now. I want the BMI to be on the Y axis (easy) and the age to be on the X axis (surprisingly difficult). If I use a line graph I can select the age to be x value using `Chart Tools > Design > Select Data`, but that does not stack the values. In other words, all of the age 5 data points would not be aligned vertically. The x axis for my example above would look like this:

```
-----------
|  |  |  |
5  6  5  7
```

If I sort my table by age I would get something like this:

```
-----------
|  |  |  |
5  5  6  7
```

If I try to make a scatter plot I get the same results.

I have tried the suggestions in the thread below, but they all give me the same thing. Please help.

[Map one column to x axis second to y axis in excel chart](https://superuser.com/questions/81398/map-one-column-to-x-axis-second-to-y-axis-in-excel-chart)

Comment: Not really clear here. I just created a chart from your data that stacks once I moved the Age data to the x-axis - assuming the additional data is in additional columns. Can you please explain the additional data? A more full example set would be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps I followed to get the image below.

1. Recreate your example data in the range `A1:B5`
2. Select the range `A1:B5`
3. On the Insert ribbon, I clicked Scatter (in the Charts group) and chose the first option

The result is shown below. I have taken no other steps to alter the chart in any way and it seems to be exactly what you want. You problem might have arisen if you started with a line chart and then tried to modify it from there. Try creating a brand new chart and see what it spits out.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Apparently I just need to isolate the columns.

Comment: yes it doesn't work if you select the names of the datapoints also... is it possible to give the points labels in any way?

Comment: @Cerveser It worked for me exactly as described above. I run Win7 with Excel 2013. It may act differently on other setups. Regarding adding labels: Yes, you can do that. Scatter charts allow labels for Series Name, X Value, Y Value, or even any text you want if you type in a range and then select it as "Value from Cells" in the data labels properties. If you have a specific question about getting them to work and can't find the answer elsewhere, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button.